# Activity not opening from IntentService

Tags: android, push-notification, intentservice

I got Push Notification in class `GcmIntentService extends IntentService` and I am trying to open my `ActivityA` from here.

It opens the activity when the app is closed, but it cannot open if my app is already running in the background.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

How to open `ActivityA` with interrupting background app?

Comment: Is launchMode of ActivityA in the Manifest set to "singleTop" ?

Comment: Yes  Farhad Faghihi, It is set to "singleTop" in the Manifest

Comment: Have you tried removing all the getApplicationContext() ? and replace them with "this"

Comment: I could not remove because startActivity(intent) method need Context.

Comment: I can use "this" instead of getApplicationContext(). But result is same

Comment: Result is remain same :(

Comment: I think you better consider using PendingIntents and NotificationManager

Answer (score 0):

I use `BroadcastReceiver` for handle message from gcm and start a intent from this class.
Try below code:

`Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CustomActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(notificationIntent);`

It works fine with me.